# <a href="#thisSection">foo</a> scroll not working but when opened in a new tab the page loads at id="thisSection"

Tags: html, href

So basically I have a page with lots of content and I need to make it easy to navigate, I decided to use the href="#something" links to make it easier to navigate the page.

unfortunately when I click any of my links, it doesnt scroll down to the right part of the page BUT if I open the links in a new tab or window it loads at the section with id="something" !!!

Anyone can help me out? cheers

EDIT:
forgot to give an example, here is the unfinished page.

http://alkypal.com.au/wine/red-wine.html

Comment: can you reproduce your problem in some simple example?

Comment: Please show what you tried, the result, and the desired result.

Comment: Do you have that id on the page you are on? Do you have js stopping the links click?  When you click the link, does the hash appear in the url? From the information you have provided, it is impossible to know what is causing the issue

Comment: sorry guys didnt realise I didnt really give you much,
I've uploaded the page temporarily so you can have a look, thanks
http://alkypal.com.au/wine/red-wine.html

Comment: I'm looking into it, found and replicated issue, will update you soon

Comment: Idk if its related but your swiper is throwing error

Comment: I believe it's related to `custom.js:83` where the default click event for `.filter-menu li` is prevented: `$('.filter-menu li').on('click', function(){ ... return false; }`. It might help generate answers if you include the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately my js is very basic, is there any easy way for me to stop that js function?

Comment: @showdev seems like you are definitely right, I just grabbed that section from another part of the template cause I liked how it looked, didnt really looked into the code. I'll just recreate that section so I wont have to worry about the js, thanks :)

Comment: A quick solution might be to remove `return false` from `custom.js:96` so the click event can finish. But I'm not sure how that might impact the intended functionality.